# Rails uniqueness of several (aggregated) columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, uniqueidentifier

I have a Rails app (Postgres) and I want to add validation based on multiple parameters.. E.g.

if

```
 Object.column1 & Object.column2 are NOT unique => reject new entry.
```

but if

```
Object.column1 IS not unique BUT Object.column2 for duplicate entry is different => accept new entry
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a scope to your uniqueness constraint. It will then only check if the whole set of columns is unique.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :column1, :scope => :column2
```

Please refer to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if :scope will solve your problem alternatively you can write your own validation like

```
validate :custom_validation

def custom_validation
  self.errors.add(:column, MESSAGE) if YOUR VALIDATION LOGIC fails
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

```
class User
  validates :first_name, :uniqueness => true, :scope => [:last_name]
end
```

You can also create a unique index, and your database will enforce uniqueness.

```
add_index :users, [:last_name, :first_name], :unique => true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safer to perform this check at the database level by using a migration to add unique indexes to [column1, column2] and [column2] like this:

```
add_index :model_name, [:column1, :column2], :unique=>true
add_index :model_name, :column2, :unique=>true
```